# chrome extension programing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am a beginner in developing Chrome extension I am having problem as below:

How can I execute a script for currently open page? I want to do it using `background.html`. I already tried to run

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', exec_fun);
```

or

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', exec_fun);
```

and also registered `backgroung.html` in `manifest.json` to execute the `exec_fun()` function, but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please send your manifest, and maybe some more code? The problem might be there. Also, try to check that you have specified the permissions you need for this (if you need any).

Answer (score 1):

if you want a script to run on every page, you should write a content script:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Content scripts run inside the page, so you can access its DOM and use its events.

On the other hand, background.html run only once on extension start up (usually when the browser opens), and it's independent from any tab or page.  Its your extension "operations base".  That's no the place where you want to put your script, except that you use a listener to catch every page change with onUpdated, that fires every time the tab's url change:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated

"and also registered backgroung.html in manifest.json to execute the exec_fun() function"

How are you trying to do that?  I think that's no the way.

Comment: No... I just informed that i have registered background.html in "background": field of manifest.json file to inform u that error is not because of that both listener i m adding inside script atg in background.html . By the way i can understand that i should use content script . Thank u for the answer !

Comment: Now the problem is that i am unable to use chrome.* api due to script defined as content_script ???

Comment: Yes, it's a security matter.  Content script can access DOM but cannot use (most of) chrome's API; background script can use Chrome's API but cannot access DOM.  Your content script should communicate with your background script: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication